# .NET Native ошибка компиляции. ChatCapabilitiesManager.GetCachedCapabilities

Tags: c#, .net, .net-native

При построении проекта в Release происходит две ошибки в двух проектах. Насколько я понял, мне нужно как-то правильно всё настроить в файле Properties/Default.rd.xml

По ссылке есть описание этого файла, но всё-таки не пришло полное понимание, что и как конкретно нужно настроить.

**Вопросы**

1. Мне нужно как-то отключить Reflection для типов, присутствующих в ошибках или для всего гигантского проекта прописать всё, что должно поддерживать Reflection?
2. Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как отключить отражение для указанных в ошибке типов?

`ChatCapabilitiesManager.GetCachedCapabilities` введён в `Windows 10, version 1809 (introduced v10.0.17763.0)` и `Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract (introduced v7)`

Я использую следующие версии:

```
<TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
<TargetPlatformVersion Condition=" '$(TargetPlatformVersion)' == '' ">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

[Runtime Directives (rd.xml) Configuration File Reference](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=391919)

```
<Directives xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2013/01/metadata">
  <Application>
    <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />
  </Application>
</Directives>
```

Первая:

> Произошла внутренняя ошибка компилятора: `MCG0021:InvalidMethodImpl`
>   Метод
>   `"Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatCapabilities>`
>   `Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatCapabilitiesManager.GetCachedCapabilitiesAsync(System.String)"`
>   не содержит допустимое значение `MethodImpl`. Каждый метод среды
>   выполнения Windows должен иметь значение `MethodImpl`, указывающее на
>   соответствующий интерфейс среды выполнения `Windows`. Библиотека среды
>   выполнения `Windows
>   "Assembly(Name=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>   Location=F:\Programming\Repos\windows-uwp-app\Xxx.Tests.Uwp\obj\x64\Release\ilc\in\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd,
>   ContentType=WindowsRuntime)"`, на которую указывает ссылка, неправильно
>   сформирована..    `Xxx.Tests.Uwp  C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets 788`

Вторая:

> Произошла внутренняя ошибка компилятора: `MCG0021:InvalidMethodImpl`
>   Метод
>   `"Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatCapabilities>`
>   `Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatCapabilitiesManager.GetCachedCapabilitiesAsync(System.String)"`
>   не содержит допустимое значение `MethodImpl`. Каждый метод среды
>   выполнения Windows должен иметь значение `MethodImpl`, указывающее на
>   соответствующий интерфейс среды выполнения `Windows`. Библиотека среды
>   выполнения Windows
>   `"Assembly(Name=Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract,
>   Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null,
>   Location=F:\Programming\Repos\windows-uwp-app\Xxx.App\obj\x64\Release\ilc\in\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd,
>   ContentType=WindowsRuntime)"`, на которую указывает ссылка, неправильно
>   сформирована..    `Xxx.App    C:\Users\UserName\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\2.1.8\tools\Microsoft.NetNative.targets 788`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло это:

В файлах двух проектов  `Properties/Default.rd.xml`

**Xxx.App**

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />

<Assembly Name="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">
  <Namespace Name="Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat" Serialize="Excluded"
             Browse="Excluded" Activate="Excluded"
             Dynamic="Excluded" XmlSerializer="Excluded" />
</Assembly>
```

**Xxx.Tests.Uwp**

```
<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Auto" />

<Assembly Name="Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract">
  <Namespace Name="Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat" Serialize="Excluded"
             Browse="Excluded" Activate="Excluded"
             Dynamic="Excluded" XmlSerializer="Excluded" />
</Assembly>
```